# Error Message at Breakpoint in Eclipse (JDI thread evaluations has encountered a prob.)

Tags: android, eclipse

for some time the attached Error Message occured in each Project. The error occurs when debugging, at a breakpoint when the debugger stops. *Step over* and *Step into* then not working (all the time by pushing step over or into the error message is popping up).
What can I do? I changed nothing at Eclipse.
Here the Version:
Android Developer Tools
Build: v21.0.0-519525
[image: Error Message]

Comment: In your debug console, do you have anything in your "Expressions" tab?

Comment: Ohhh yes there was an old Expression. Thanks a lot, I overlooked it.

Comment: No problem, will post as an answer in case others have this error. Glad I could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes certain Expressions in the debug window will cause this error. I have read different reasons that can cause it (variables returning null, variables in background task, trying to access xml views). I still haven't found the exact cause but it seems as though many different types of expressions can cause this error. Simply remove possible problem expressions and run your program again and you should be good.

If anyone has a better explanation as to why this happens, feel free to edit.